# Query multiple post of which one by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, taxonomy

I want to query two post types: 'projects' all of them and 'posts' by taxonomy 'light'. Does someone know how can this be achieved?

Kris

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by automatically adding the tag 'light' to all my projects. And then query all the post and projects with the light tag like this:

Query post by taxonomy tag 'light':

```
$args = array(
   'post_type'      => array( 'projects' , 'post' ),
   'tax_query'      => array(
   'relation'       => 'OR',
        array(
          'taxonomy'    => 'post_tag',
          'field'       => 'name',
          'terms'       => 'light'
        )
     ),
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
);

query_posts( $args );
```

Add tag 'light' to all projects on publish:

```
add_action('publish_projects', 'projects_post_type_tagging', 10, 2);

function projects_post_type_tagging($post_id, $post){
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, 'light', 'post_tag', true );
}
```

It's not the most elegant solution but it works. If theres a better way to solve this problem i've would like to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP_Query paramether tag__in to show posts associated with that tag. 
You can read it here : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters

Answer (score -1):

Have you registered any custom taxonomy for projects and posts? what is the slug of that taxonomy?

```
$args = array(
             'post_type' => array('post_type_1', 'post_type_2'), 
             'posts_per_page' => -1,
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'taxonomy-slug' => 'category-slug'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Nope, the taxonomy I use for the post are the 'tags'. The term of this tag should be 'light'.

Comment: Fixed it with adding automatically adding the tag 'light' to projects.